# Doubt in definition of Float

Tags: floating-point, c

Can anyone tell the meaning of the bold portion?

> Float: It is used to store decimal numbers **(numbers with floating point value) with single precision.**

Comment: Any decent textbook on C (and even related languages) covers this.

Comment: Also, if you are quoting something in a question, please at least surround it with quotation marks. It took me a minute to make sense of what you were really asking.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking about some text on this page: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-types-in-c/

The text about the `float` type is intended to say that `float` stores a [single precision floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) value. The "single precision" refers to a specific well-known format for storing floating point values in computers; single precision values are 32 bits in size.

Floating point values are values represented internally in a fashion somewhat similar to scientific notation but using 2 instead of 10 as the number raised to a power. The 32 bits are separated in a *sign*, *exponent*, and *mantissa*, and the value stored by a floating point variable is:

$$
(-1)^\mathit{sign} \times 2^\mathit{exponent} \times (1.\mathit{mantissa})
$$

(Technically here, I'm talking about *binary* floating point, but that's what C's `float` type is.)

In a single precision float, the exponent is eight bits wide and the mantissa is twenty-three bits. (the sign is always one bit in any size floating point value)

The practical upshot of this is that you can use `float` variables to store real values that aren't integers; for example 1.5 or 3.14159. You should be aware that the way binary floating point numbers work is sometimes confusing and frustrating to new programmers; a basic guide to those issues can be found at https://floating-point-gui.de/.